# How can I keep my warm hands from making polymer clay too soft?

Tags: polymer-clay, sculpting

I have unnaturally warm hands, which heat up very quickly as I use them, to the point of sweating when playing video games or sculpting!

This affects my polymer clay, because my hands make it too soft to work with.

I've tried using a desk fan blowing on my hands, which works, but it often cools the clay as well, making it too stiff!

What can I do? Are there methods of cooling my hands that won't cool the sculpture? Are there tools I can use that suitably substitute for my fingers?

Comment: Obviously, your desk fan has effect, only too much. Could you place it further away, and find the optimal distance to get your clay 'just right'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I might try two things, one handle the clay as little as required, the less you touch it the less heat it will absorb.  And maybe try something like [Wristband coolers](http://www.aquacoolkeeper.com/gb/cooling-for-people/cooling-wristband.html).  The link is to one brand, but the idea is that you can cool down your whole body with these.  It is a band that wraps your wrist (where you have a lot blood vessels).  I'll run my wrists under cool water on hot summer days and it will cool me off just as well as a bucket over the head, without the mess. So being able to cool down your hands should be possible and might work well enough to get you where you need.

Comment: Oh, neat! I was thinking of Ace bandaging ice packs around my wrists, but that's unwieldly!